# Observable from an array doesn't work in TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to create an observable from an array, as documentation says in https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/observable.md:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
let theList = Observable.from(sites);
```

but I get:

```
TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.from is not a function
```

my goal is to use operators like `reduce` or `scan` over a Observable sequence, as a standard `Observable` seems to not support, as below:

```
this.theList = new Observable(observer => {
  // this works
  observer.next(sites);
});

this.sub = this.theList.reduce(function() {
  // this is never called
  return acc;
}).subscribe(l => {
  // this is never called
  this.finalList = l;
});
```

The code can be found in this Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/cKEqtp (`src/app.ts`).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple solutions :

## 1 - Import specific element

In your example, you are just importing the `Observable`, however, you use the `.from()` method in order to create an observable from an array. So you have to import the `.from()` method if you want to use it. That is the same for the `reduce` operator.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/reduce';
```

## 2 - Import all operator and method

`Observable` is being brought in from `rxjs/Rx`, so pulling it in this way will **automatically** get you all of the operators and method.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

## What is the difference ?

The big difference between these two approach is that you will not import all operators at once by using the first approach. It can be useful when you're working in production mode.

Answer (score 1):

You are importing the minimal `Observable`:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

so to use `from`, you need this import, too:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
```