# Returning Inner Block Observable Object

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angularfire2, angular2-observables

I want to return a single object from my Firebase database that has the highest quality rating in the past 7 days. I'm using the following Typescript code to, first, query all threads created in the past seven days and, second, to extract the thread with the highest value at `quality`. Ideally, I can just "transform" the `results` observable into the final iterated object of the forEach statement.

```
highestWeek: Number = 0;

...

getWeeksBest(): Observable<any> {
    let now = Date.now() / 1000;
    let results = this.af.database.list('/threads', {
        query: {
            orderByChild: 'created',
            startAt: now - 604800 //One week ago
        }
    })
    .map(results => {
        results.forEach(result => {
            if (result.quality > this.highestWeek) {
                console.log(result) //Logs next highest quality thread
                this.highestWeek = result.quality       
            }
        })
    })
    results.subscribe(results => console.log(results)) //Undefined
    return results //Undefined
}
```

Comment: In your `.map` you are not transforming the results, you are doing a side effect. If you can immediately transform `results` do the transformation in the mapping function and **return** the transformed value, if you want to do something async use `flatMap` - with that operator you can map to other observables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return an observable that emits the thread with the highest quality within the last week, the function you pass to the `map` operator needs to return a value (as mentioned in other answers).

Also, you need to decide upon what behaviour should be expected if there are no threads. Should the resultant observable be empty? Or should it emit `null`?

The internal subscription is probably best avoided - you will make an additional subscription with each call and said subscription is never unsubscribed. And it would be better to avoid the side-effect, too, as the highest quality will be made available by the emitted thread.

You could do something like this, instead:

```
getWeeksBest(): Observable<any> {

    let now = Date.now() / 1000;
    let best = this.af.database.list('/threads', {
        query: {
            orderByChild: 'created',
            startAt: now - 604800 //One week ago
        }
    })

    // Filter out empty lists of threads, so that the resultant
    // observable emits nothing if there are no threads:

    .filter(threads => threads.length > 0)

    // Use Array.prototype.reduce to return the thread with the
    // highest quality:

    .map(threads => threads.reduce(
      (acc, thread) => thread.quality > acc.quality ? thread : acc
    ));
    return best;
}
```

If you want to emit `null` if there are no threads, remove the `filter` and change the `map` to:

```
.map(threads => (threads.length === 0) ? null : threads.reduce(
  (acc, thread) => thread.quality > acc.quality ? thread : acc
))
```

Comment: This solution directly addresses my specific question. Thanks, @cartant.

Comment: Between the shorthand functions and the observable operators, both of which are new to me, I'm losing track of what's happening in my functions. I'd benefit from some reading up on shorthand functions first, I suppose. Although the core problem here was understanding how to transform the FirebaseListObservable to the object. What's happening there is still pretty fuzzy to me. Do you know of any blogposts that explore this area in depth?

Comment: This seems to explain [array reduce](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/boiling-down-arrays-with-array-reduce.html) well enough. For RxJS: [RxJS In-Depth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KOOT7BArVHQ); [Intro to Reactive Programming](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754); and [Don’t Unsubscribe](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87).

Comment: The RxJS5 documentation is very much a work in progress, but there is a lot of [RxJS4 documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/tree/master/doc) that is useful. The breaking changes between the versions are [detailed here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md).

Answer (score 1):

So the question is probably why you're getting `undefined` in the `subscribe(...)` callback in `results` variable.

In `.map()` you're using the short arrow syntax to create a block of code but this means you have to use a `return` statement.

```
.map(results => {
   results.forEach(result => {
       if (result.quality > this.highestWeek) {
           console.log(result) //Logs next highest quality thread
           this.highestWeek = result.quality       
       }
   });
   return results; 
})
```

In your case I'd be even better to use `.do()` operator instead of `.map()`.

At the end of `getWeeksBest()` you're returning the Observable so the last line is definitely not returning `undefined`.

```
getWeeksBest(): Observable<any> {
    let now = Date.now() / 1000;
    let results = this.af.database.list('/threads', {
        ...
    });
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

martin is right you need to add an `return` statement. But also keep in mind that Array.forEach is always returning `undefined`. So in your case you could use `Array.map`.

But overall i would suggest something like this:

```
getAllThreads$(): Observable<any[]> {
  let now = Date.now() / 1000;
  return this.af.database.list('/threads', {
    query: {
        orderByChild: 'created',
        startAt: now - 604800 //One week ago
    }
  })
}

getWeeksBest$():Observable<number>{
  return this.getAllThreads$().map(threads => Array.isArray(threads )? threads.reduce((highestQuality, thread) => {
   let currentQuality = thread? thread.quality: 0;
   return currentQuality > highestQuality? currentQuality: highestQuality;
  }, 0): 0);
}
```

and somewhere in your class constructor just subscribe to `getWeeksBest$`

Answer (score 1):

RxJS provides numerous operator to perform data transformation. In your case, you want to retrieve an object with the highest `quality` value, so we can use the **reduce** operator where we will apply a `maxBy()` function.

```
const weeks = [
    {
      quality: 1
    },
    {
      quality: 15
    },
    {
      quality: 5
    },
    {
      quality: 8
    }
  ];


//maxBy stateless function (you can see a currified function)
const maxBy = (prop) => (a, b) => a[prop] > b[prop] ? a : b;

//Fetch data and apply the maxBy when the reduce is perform over the collection
function fetchData() {
  //You can perform some async actions
  return Rx
    .Observable
    .from(weeks)
    .reduce(maxBy('quality'), 0);
}

fetchData().subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Feel free to check the example on [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/lUvJe0FSmwkH4Ui75FZo?p=preview)

Comment: Trypescript is complaining about `from` for some reason, and `import 'rxjs/add/operator/from';` isn't changing that.

Comment: Be sure to import Observable, from, and reduce operator, or the whole rxJs. You can check a previous post that I made [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38845719/observable-from-an-array-doesnt-work-in-typescript/38846326#38846326)

Comment: I had imported `Observable`, but for some reason I was unable to import `from` using the statement in the above comment.